# I am calculating the squared differences , getting the shape error. Could you please point out where I can change the code to rectify errors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

#### Shapes of few variables involved in the code:

wbar -  (10, 3)
row_weights_permuted - (240, 4)
w0_new - (12,)

```
def LossFun2(w0_new):
    wbar = np.array(optimized_weights1)


    predicted_w1barbar = np.matmul(row_weights_permuted, w0_new[:4]).reshape((-1, 3))
    predicted_w2barbar = np.matmul(row_weights_permuted, w0_new[4:8]).reshape((-1, 3))
    predicted_w3barbar = np.matmul(row_weights_permuted, w0_new[8:12]).reshape((-1, 3))

    predicated_wbarbar = np.hstack((predicted_w1barbar, predicted_w2barbar, 
                                     predicted_w3barbar))

    loss = ((predicated_wbarbar - wbar)**2).sum()
    return loss

w0_new = np.ones(12) * (1/3)
result = LossFun2(w0_new)
print("LossFun2 Values",result)
```

#### Error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (80,9) (10,3)
```

Comment: my guess is that `predicated_wbarbar` is the (80,9), being the hstack of 3 (80,3) arrays.  I don't know your intensions here.